# Render different layouts in react depending on screen's size ( responsive )

Tags: reactjs

Is there any library or something that can allow me to change mi layout depending on the screen's size?

I'm getting to a point in my projects where, using media queries isn't enough and i would love being able to change the design of my App when using a phone for example

Let me give you an example...

```
const size = min-width: 900px;

const layout = () => {

return(

<>
{size && <smallLayout />}

{!size && <Layout />
</>

)

}
```

If you know something that can help me with that, please share it with me, i'll thank you for it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For device or browser detection you can use a package like: [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect)

They also provide components for you; but you dont have to use it; you can still use ısMobile parameter to conditionaly render your own different components.

```
<BrowserView>
    <h1> This is rendered only in browser </h1>
</BrowserView>
<MobileView>
    <h1> This is rendered only on mobile </h1>
</MobileView>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! that looks awesome, i'll try that out